# What should I put on the whereKey:@"objectId"?

Tags: ios, parsing, objectid, pfquery

I'm using iOS.

If I insert @"objectId" in the whereKey:@"". I get an error saying: bad special key: objectId.

This is my code:

```
PFQuery *findFriends = [PFUser query];
[findFriends whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:friendsID];
[findFriends selectKeys:@[@"firstname",@"lastname"]];
[findFriends findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", objects);
    }
}];
```

friendsID is an NSString with the objectId from the user the current user is following.

Thank you!

Comment: I've compared objectId's this way in the past, is your 'friendsID' variable definitely an objectId string? Can you show how you sign it or NSLog(@"%@",friendsID) before the query and tell me the value.

Comment: @Logan Yes, the friendsID is an objectId. The value: qvcFLA9vHs

Comment: @Logan NSString *friendsID = [[friends objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"toUser"];

Comment: I just used your exact code with no problems. Literally, copied and pasted into Xcode and it ran fine. Not sure why you're getting this.  Do you have some sort of ACL on the user that might prevent access?

Comment: Is 'friends' array an array of strings, or an array of PFUsers?

Comment: friends in an NSArray of strings, so I get the first string. Since it is only one.. and that string values, the objectId: qvcFLA9vHs

Comment: Hi John, I don't think it's a string.  If I do your code with a string everything works fine.  If I use a PFUser, I get the same error you're getting.

Comment: You're right Logan! It is a PFUser. But if it is a PFUser, do you have any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your friendsID is not actually a string, my guess is that it's a PFUser.  If this is the case, then one way to do it would be to user this.

```
PFUser * toUser = [friends[0] objectForKey:@"toUser"];
PFQuery * findFriends = [PFUser query];
[findFriends whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:toUser.objectId];
[findFriends selectKeys:@[@"firstname",@"lastname"]];
[findFriends findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", objects);
    }
}];
```